# Is this the correct way to extract U and V wind components from NEXRAD weather radar?

Tags: meteorology, wind, python, radar

I am working with NEXRAD radar data, and I am trying to plot the U and V wind velocity for each point on a grid. There is a channel in the data called "Velocity" described as "[A measure of the radial component of the wind either toward the radar (negative values) or away from the radar (positive values)](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/radar/next-generation-weather-radar)"

I am using the [Py-Art library to create a grid](https://arm-doe.github.io/pyart/notebooks/mapping_data_to_a_cartesian_grid.html) of this velocity data. Now that I have a grid of the velocity (m/s) and angle (theta) for each point on my grid, can I simply calculate the U and V velocties with sin and cos?

[image: Calculating U and V components]

Comment: Keep in mind that because it only gives you towards/away, you are missing a component of the two-dimensional field.  For example, due west of the radar... you have no north\south (v) data known at all.    Looks like papers like [this one](https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/atot/35/8/jtech-d-18-0004.1.xml) offer some help, based upon changes over time, but indeed single doppler has some shortcomings.